# SQL Server 2008 - Cannot order data using formatted Date

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I run the following SQL I get the date formatted the way I need it:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), convert(datetime, [Tran_Date], 103), 3), 4, 5) AS 'Date', 
    SUM([TRAN_AMOUNT]) as 'Amount' 
FROM [TRANSACTIONS] 
group by SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), convert(datetime, [Tran_Date], 103), 3), 4, 5)  
order by SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), convert(datetime, [Tran_Date], 103), 3), 4, 5)
```

But the results are incorrect as the 01/14 is before the 12/13 because have had to convert to a string to get the mm/yy format.

```
01/14   4159.52
12/13   24231.60
```

When I change the Order by or Group by so that the data is a date datatype I get the error:

> TRANSACTIONS.Tran_Date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

I'm sure this must be a huge issue but I can't seem to find anything. Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: What about if you keep GROUP BY as it is, and only change order by to `ORDER BY [Tran_Date]` ?

Comment: Then I get the TRANSACTIONS.Tran_Date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), convert(datetime, [Tran_Date], 103), 3), 4, 5) AS 'Date', 
    SUM([TRAN_AMOUNT]) as 'Amount' 
FROM [TRANSACTIONS] 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), convert(datetime, [Tran_Date], 103),112),
         SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 
         convert(datetime, [Tran_Date], 103), 3), 4, 5)  
order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), convert(datetime, [Tran_Date], 103),112)
```

Comment: Sorry Lamak, no use, still trying to order by a string and the group by doesn't group by the mm/yy format in the select. the data is for use on a chart.

Comment: So in summary, I need to format the date as mm/yy (string) but order the date as a datetime datatype, so that the months and year follow as you would expect.

Comment: @DennisFinke And that is exactly what the query should be doing, are you sure that you are using the exact same query as my answer?

Comment: @DennisFinke Apparently, the column wasn't originally a `DATETIME`. Updated my answer to take that into account

Comment: Dude, thank you, works a treat. I don't understand why (i'll be studying this all night) but I'm glad it's working.

Comment: Oh and you are right, it is a string value, I thought it would be easier when creating the database but should have created the column as datetime, would save a lot of conversion.